# How do I configure Team Foundation Server 2010 to allow me to use Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to create a New Team Project in Visual Studio using Git. I'm connecting to Team Foundation Server 2010, and when I get to the **Specify Source Control Settings** dialog, the **version control system** drop down doesn't allow me to select anything other than Team Foundation Version Control.

How do I configure Team Foundation Server 2010 to allow me to use Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for Git in TFS was a feature introduced in TFS 2013.  So if you're using TFS 2010 the answer is you can't.